# How to cache templates in Blaze?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am implementing an application called RadGrad (http://radgrad.ics.hawaii.edu) and the "degree planner" page takes 4-8 seconds to display:

[image]

Thinking that this was a problem with subscriptions, we implemented SubsManager for subscription caching.  From profiling with Kadira, we now know that subscriptions are cached and that this is not a cause of slow page display times; going back and forth between the "home" and "degree planner" pages shows a consistent multi-second wait time, but no subscription-related events:

[image]

So we're trying to figure out what to try next (other than move to React), and one idea is to cache Templates as well as subscriptions.  Arunoda showed an example of how this could help in a three minute YouTube video a while back:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EF2PAUrVvQ

Unfortunately, I can't find further details, so I'm asking the community for guidance.  I am willing to pay the 4 second overhead to display the page the first time, as long as it displays quickly from then on.  Are there blog posts, packages, or example code out there that we can use to implement Template caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally never done this but have seen the video as well.  You probably already found these resources, but if not, here you go.

- [Arunoda's discussion of this on meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/making-blaze-faster/5762/23)
- [Arunoda's template caching code](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/9e3997d9c8d8d73a16f7)
- [Discussion in ways to make blaze faster (virtual DOM, template caching, etc.)](https://medium.com/parlay-engineering/fixing-your-meteor-app-s-render-performance-a727e918511c#.o5su99mwi)

Post back if you get something effective in place!